# How can I see the "Created by" and "Modified By in the headers on an Inbound Email Message?

Tags: email2case

Somebody knows where SalesForce takes the value of "Created by" and "Modified By"when using Incoming Emails. I have issue that those values are taking by default from somewhere and it's incorrect.
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure it's a setting under case settings, it's probably the default case creator. I'm not in position to confirm at the moment but check there.

Answer (score 0):

Look under Build > Customize > Cases > Supports Settings
There is a field called "Automated Case User" with the description:

> The user listed in the Case History related list for automated case
>   changes from:
>
> • Assignment rules
>
> • Escalation rules
>
> • On-Demand Email-to-Case
>
> • Cases logged in the Self-Service portal